# Use of imbedding in Rotman's Invariance of Dimension proof

Tags: algebraic-topology

I understand everything in this proof except for the highlighted part below.

I've studied Introduction to Manifolds (Tu), but I don't have enough context here to understand what the imbedding $g$ is or why it exists.

> [image]

Comment: The idea is that it is fairly obvious that you can embed a lower dimensional simplex in a higher dimensional one so that the image has empty interior. Think about a line segment in a triangle or a triangle in a tetrahedron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many such maps $g$. Here's one approach.

First, embed $\Delta^p$ into $\Delta^m$ as a face. For example, $(x_0, ..., x_p) \mapsto (x_0, ..., x_p, 0, ... 0)$.

Then embed $\Delta^m$ into its own interior by shrinking it a bit. For example, take $t$ to be the barycenter of $\Delta^m$, and take $x \mapsto (x + t)/2$.

Then take the composite of these two maps.

**EDIT**: All this makes good intuitive sense, but I realize I never actually proved the that the image of $\Delta^p$ contains no nonempty open subsets of the interior of $\Delta^m$. But this is pretty clear if we look at the homeomorphic situation of $\Bbb{R}^p$ embedded into $\Bbb{R}^m$ via the first $p$ coordinates (imagine, say, $p = 2$ and $m = 3$). If a point $x \in \Bbb{R}^p$ is in an open subset $U \subseteq \Bbb{R}^m$, we can find a basic open set $x \in V \subseteq U$ where $V$ is a product of open intervals, and then it's clear that $V$ can't lie inside $\Bbb{R}^p$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't exactly understand all the details of the proof given, but I believe it is very easy to see why such an embedding should exist: you can just have something like the map
$$\Delta^p\to(\Delta^m),\ (x_1,\dots,x_p)\mapsto\left(x_1,\dots,x_p,0,\dots,0\right)$$
composed with a map that shrinks $\Delta^m$ to its interior, as in the accepted answer (credits to Hew Wolff for giving a correct map, initially I thoughtlessly gave a wrong one). The idea is that you want to embed a lower dimensional simplex in a higher dimensional one without it touching the boundary and in a non-crazy way (no pathological space filling stuff) so that the image has empty interior. There will be many maps doing this.

Edit: my original answer was wrong, I edited it just to confirm that the other answer is correct, to avoid confusion (originally I didn't have enough reputation to comment, I should have been more careful before answering).

Comment: As I said, I would have liked this to be a comment, I am not sure it answers your question... feel free to ask for more details if you need.

Comment: This conceptually makes sense, but the image of your function isn't contained in $\Delta^m$ (let alone it's interior). The sum of the coordinates are greater than 1. Am I misunderstanding this mapping?

Comment: Nah, you are indeed right, I didn't think about the map thoroughly. The other answer has the right approach (I will edit accordingly).